# How to read images in android

Tags: android, image, pixel, rgb

Objective : read an image and get its RGB pixel values .

Problem : thing is that i had created a new folder(img) under project(testing) in eclipse and had pasted a .jpg file(test.jpg) and tried to read it with this code :

tig = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/testing/img/test.jpg");
            AlertDialog.Builder bld=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            bld.setTitle("hurray");
            int pxl = tig.getPixel(30, 40);
            bld.setMessage(pxl);
            bld.show();
but at runtime application used to "Unfortunately close" , then i tried placing image in the asset folder and decodestream , no use .

question 
1. is it not possible to create my own folder in project and place files there 
2. or where should i place the image to read its pixels .

I need real spoon feeding here , coz im new to android development .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can place image files in your drawable folder and read it from there.

Comment: But how , can you piece write a piece of code to explain . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, I am guessing this is what you need

change

```
Bitmap src = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimagename);
```

to

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.yourimagename);
```

and check again

```
Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
for(int x = 0;x < bitmap.getWidth();x++)
    for(int y = 0;y < bitmap.getHeight();y++)
    {
   // here bitmap.getPixel(x, y)) gets the pixel at the position (x,y)  
   int pixelvalue = bitmap.getPixel(x, y));
    int rValue = color.red(pixelvalue); // gives value of R in "RGB"
    int gValue = color.green(pixelvalue); // gives value of G in "RGB"
    int bValue = color.blue(pixelvalue); // gives value of B in "RGB"
}
```

Place your drawable here

[image]

Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks a lot , but still  thing what i don't understand is that where should i place the image file under project ?

Comment: And it says "bitmapdrawable cannot be typecasted to bitmap" and if i change bitmap to bitmapdrawable in 1st word in 1st line of your code , then it throws error in the first line saying " src.copy" method is not possible or something

Comment: Bitmap tig=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
int pxl = tig.getPixel(30, 40);
AlertDialog.Builder bld=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
bld.setTitle("hurray");
bld.setMessage(pxl);  bld.show();

Comment: i have tried to use the above code , it still closes "Unfortunately" :(

Comment: Bitmap tig=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     
     int pxl = tig.getPixel(30, 40);
     AlertDialog.Builder bld=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        bld.setTitle("hurray");
        
          bld.setMessage(pxl);
           bld.show();

Comment: Thank you so much it worked , i had to convert string to integer :)

Comment: Oh. sorry i havent seen the messages.
Any how, you made it to work. 
Happy Coding.
And if there is any edit needed in the answer, You can do it so that, it would help others